# Complex space over Real space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the set of vectors { $1 + i, 1 - i$} $ \subset \mathbb{C}$ is linearly dependent if  $\mathbb{C}$ is taken as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and independent if $\mathbb{C}$ is taken as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

I do not want a solution to this. I was able to solve it but I do not understand the exact meaning of it.

If $\mathbb{C}$ is a space over $\mathbb{R}$ then how can the set even exist ? It says that the given set is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$. So if $\mathbb{C}$ is over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ will have only a real part. Hence the set cannot exist as all the elements of the set have a complex part. But this is not what happens. Why is that ?

Set A being a proper subset of set B does not mean that all linear combinations of set A are also in B. So the part where we can take only real constants in linear combination or complex constants in linear combination should not be right.

What am I understanding wrong ? Please help me out

These are not 2 separate questions but just one question which I generalized. So please dont close my question.

Comment: Look at the definition of  a vector space over  a field  and verify that $\mathbb  C$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$. That should clear your doubts.

Comment: Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \Bbb F$ be such that $\lambda_1(1+i)+\lambda_2(1-i)=0$. Here $\Bbb F$ is either the scalar field $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Now, $$\lambda_1(1+i)+\lambda_2(1-i)=0$$$$\implies \lambda_1=-\lambda_2\frac{(1-i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=-\lambda_2\cdot\frac{-2i}{2}=i\lambda_2$$ So, both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ can not be real. In other words, $\{1+i,1-i\}$ can not be linearly independent over $\Bbb R$, but lineraly dependent over $\Bbb C$ as $i\cdot (1+i)+1\cdot(1-i)=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so what I understood is that a space over a field means that I take the vector from the space, constant from field. After scalar multiplication and addition, the result should still be in the space ? Could you just confirm the previous line ? also, thanks for the help

Comment: @Sumanta thanks for the explanation ! But turns out I was wrong about what a space over a field means.